# How to update array adapter using timer/handler?

Tags: android, listview, timer, adapter, handler

I get the data from API such as printer name, model and  status and displaying in the listview in array adapter.In my program I am testing if the printer is idle or not and showing by using green(idle) and red (busy)  circles in the listview , but my issue is that the state has to be constantly checked and get updated to display on screen green or red circle, for this case I was checking out into  handler and timers and tried to implement it but unsuccessfully - nothing worked. I am unsure which one is better to use and how , since I am using array adapter.

If you have any insights, please let me know.

My adapter class:

```
public class NsdServiceInfoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PrinterNew> {
private Context mContext;
private List<PrinterNew> services;
private InetAddress hostAddress;


//Creating new constructor with parameters such as this class(context), layout id (list item layout Id) and data model.

public NsdServiceInfoAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int layoutId, List<PrinterNew> list) {
    super(context, layoutId, list);
    mContext = context;
    services = list;
}

@NonNull
@Override


public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull 
ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItem = convertView;

    //Checking if view is empty then we inflate our list  layout.
    if (listItem == null)
        listItem = 
LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

    //Getting data's position in the data set.
    final PrinterNew currentService = services.get(position);



    final ImageView i = listItem.findViewById(R.id.status_circle);
    TextView t = listItem.findViewById(R.id.TextView_serviceName);
    final TextView r = listItem.findViewById(R.id.TextView_serviceIP);
    r.setText(currentService.getPrinterModel());
    t.setText(currentService.getPrinterName());


    if (currentService.isIdle()) {
        i.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(42, 187, 155));
    } else {
        i.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(240, 52, 52));
    }





    return listItem;
}

}
```

My printer class

```
public PrinterNew() {

}

public String getPrinterName() {
    return printerName;
}

public void setPrinterName(String printerName) {
    this.printerName = printerName;
}

public String getPrinterModel() {
    return printerModel;
}

public String getPrinterInformation() {
    return this.printInformation;
}

public void setPrinterInformation(String url, Context context, final VolleyCallback callback) {
    Log.d("API", "Currently calling URL " + url);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    queue.add(new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("API", "Print information" + response);
            String temp = response.substring(2, response.length() - 2);
            byte msgArray[];
            try {
                msgArray = temp.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
                state = msgArray[0];
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            printInformation = response;
            callback.onSuccess(printInformation);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("API", "Print information nope ");
            callback.onFailure(error);
        }
    }));
}

public String getMenuInformation() {
    return menuInformation;
}

public void setMenuInformation(String url, Context context, final VolleyCallback callback) {
    Log.d("API", "Currently calling URL " + url);

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    queue.add(new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {


            String temp = response.substring(2, response.length() - 2);
            Log.d("API", "Current menu" + response);
            byte msgArray[];
            try {
                msgArray = temp.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
                currentMenu = msgArray[0];
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            menuInformation = response;
            callback.onSuccess(menuInformation);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("API", "Current menu Nope ");
            callback.onFailure(error);
        }
    }));
}


public boolean isIdle() {
    if (state == -1 && currentMenu == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


public void setPrinterService(NsdServiceInfo service) {
    this.printerService = service;
}

public NsdServiceInfo getPrinterService() {
    return this.printerService;
}


public interface VolleyCallback {
    void onSuccess(String result);

    void onFailure(Object response);
}

public void setPrinterModel(String url, Context context, final VolleyCallback callback) {
    Log.d("API", "Currently calling URL " + url);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    queue.add(new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("API", "printer model nope ");
            callback.onFailure(error);
        }
    }));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

use recyclerview.

to refresh your list whenever there is data change in the list with recyclerview, you need to user `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

but catch here is you need to get exact object in the list, the update it then refresh it with above line.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() for each specific htttp request  , it updates each time I restart the app :(